# Javascript runtime error: Cannot read property content from undefined

Tags: javascript, httpclient, getresponse

I have some tricky test case with JScript. I have nested for-loop in Javascript. In the outer loop and the inner loop also I have the below statements (with different variable, but statements are similar) to execute the client requests.

```
var targetURL = "http://firsturl.com";
var targetURL_Req = new Request(targetURL, "GET", authHeaders);
var targetClientReq = httpClient.send(targetURL_Req);
targetClientReq.waitForComplete();
targetClientRes = JSON.parse(targetClientReq.getResponse().content);
```

When the loop is running, for some values in the loop, I am getting successful response. But for some, it is giving the response as below. The tricky part is, if I execute multiple times, then the failure is coming at random places.

```
Execution of ParseJSONResponse failed with error: Javascript runtime error: \"TypeError: Cannot read property \"content\" from undefined. (ParseJSONResponse.js:7)
```

Initially I thought like one particular value is giving this error. But, the error is coming randomely. What ever value it was failed previously, getting success in the next execution and vice versa. But the error always coming is standard as mentioned above.

Am I missing any major thing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears some of the HTTP Request didn't return value caused the error. You can try add the code snippet below:

```html
// Get and Process the response
if (targetClientReq.isSuccess()) {
    var responseObj = targetClientReq.getResponse().content;
    return responseObj.access_token;
} else if (targetClientReq.isError()) {
    throw new Error(exchange.getError());
}
```

See more: https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/antipatterns/wait-for-complete

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It is working now. But it is not actually resolved the issue. It is ignoring the error. Thats one way solved my issue. But still could not understand what exactly was causing the issue

Comment: Glad I can help. If you nested http request inside a loop, it means it'll send multiple requests to the other end of your request. Depends on the workload on the other end, sometime the request can be failed/rejected. Check the network in your debugger, and see how many request send out to the destination, and see if some of them failed.